# Why do the features extracted with matcaffe_demo.m and matcaffe_batch.m for the same input are different?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, caffe

I am using Caffe to extract features with matlab wrapper.I have 5011 images as test data set.I chopped all the layers after `'relu7'` in `'deploy.prototxt'`. I found out if you take the same image as input of `matcaffe_demo.m` and `matcaffe_batch.m`, you will get the different 4096-dim features.
Could someone tell me why?
what is the differences between you extract features from all these images one by one with `matcaffe_demo.m` and extract features by listing all these images with `matcaffe_batch.m`?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to this question [at caffe github](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2689).
Basically, `matcaffe_demo` is used for classification and it **averages** results of 10 crops of the input image, while `matcaffe_bathc` uses only a single input.

Moreover, note that these m-files are no longer available in recent caffe versions.